(Record Triggered) Flow Issue: Deletes Event Records as expected in Debug Mode but, when Active, it Deletes all Events in Series
Hi everyone and thank you in advance for reading this.
I have a Record-Triggered flow on the Event object.
The Goal is to prevent newly Created or Updated Events from overlapping (conflicting) with existing Events that share the same Record Type, have the same Assignee, and either have the Subjct of "PTO" or "ACMO/On Call"
Although there might be Apps on the AppExchange that can be used, this is not an option at this point in time (company uses Calendar Anything and they want $15,000 to create a solution).
I am doing this project to help out my gf who is an Admin with the purpose of learning more about the Salesforce platform.
If the newly Created or Updated Event does conflict with an existing Event, it should DELETE any newly created/updated Event that conflicts with an existing Event that matches criteria.
Ideally, if the new Event is recurring, it should ONLY remove those specific Event instances that directly conflict and not all of the Event instances that remain.
Example - Event 1 (already exists)

Subject = "PTO", Record Type = "Scheduling Event", OwnerId = "000000000000001"
Repeats every Thursday for 2 weeks
Starts on Nov. 14th and Ends on Nov. 21
Is All Day
this means 2 Event Records (2 Activity Ids - 3 when you include the Master Id for the Recurrence)

Event 2 (newly created)

Subject = "ACMO/On Call", Record Type = "Scheduling Event", OwnerId = "000000000000001"
Repeats every Thursday for 3 weeks
Starts on Nov 14th and Ends on Nov. 28th
any time of day (could be all day)
This means 3 Event Records (3 Activity Ids - 4 when you include the Master Activity Id for the Recurrence)

My goal is that when I save the newly created "ACMO/On Call" event series, it should enter this Flow after I click "save" and from there it should delete the first 2 Event Records (Nov. 14th and Nov. 21) in this series as they conflict with the 2 Event Records for the existing PTO Event. BUT, it should NOT delete the Event Record for November 28th.
When the Flow is "Active" I test this by creating an Event (let's call it "Event 1") that is "All Day" and Repeats weekly (like, every Thursday) for 2 weeks - so, 2 Events.
Next, I create another Recurring Event ("Event 2") that begins on the same Day and repeats weekly for 3 weeks - so, 3 Events. But, the first 2 Events should be Deleted right away after I save and only the last Event should remain.
However, when this Flow is ACTIVE it deletes all 3 Events??
Trying to figure this out, I DEACTIVATE the Flow. I delete every existing Event (including any Master Events) to get a clean calendar. I repeat the process above:
Event 1: Every Thursday - ALL DAY - for 2 Thursdays
Event 2: EVery Thursday - for 3 Thursdays.
I then DEBUG my flow using Event 2 and it works as expected, it only deletes 2 Events and keeps the final Event
This Record triggered flow fires AFTER SAVE on Create and Update. It checks the Triggering Event, gets any related Recurring Events (to include the "unseen" Master Event).
I use a Collection Sort Element after this Get Records element. The reason is I found, if sorted "Ascending", the FIRST record retrieved when there is recurrence is the "Master Event". Tested by loading this Event Id into the browser URL and when I delete that Event it deletes the whole series.
So, I loop through the Get Records ("Get Related Recurring Events") and add the found Event Records to a Collection Variable (varCollectRecurringEvents) using an Assignment Element. HOWEVER, I aslo have a Counter Variable to find the First Record - if more than one was found (i.e. it's Recurring) and I remove this from the Record Collection Variable. This is done because I found that if the Master Record is in that collection and looped later, it will also conflict and then the Series gets deleted.
I store that Master Event Record in a Single Record Collection variable named "varStoreFirstRecord". This works fine and gets the expected records including the Master, if it exists, and properly removes the Master from the varCollectRecurringEvents Collection.
While looping the Get Related Recurring Events I also store all Activity Ids (including the Master Event if it exists) in a Text Template. I have a counter variable and a Decision Element and other logic that works just fine and as expected. I'll leave that out right now but can explain later, if needed.
Next, I perform a Get Records (named "Get Events that match") for ALL Events "Not In" that Text Template that meet the criteria (same Record Type Id, one of 2 Subjects, and same OwnerId/Assigned to Id) - This works as expected and finds Event records to check for conflicts.
Since I will have a nested loop coming up, I Loop through "Get Events that match" and assign them to a Record Collection variable named "varCollectMatchingEvents".
Now begins the fun part.
I have an Outer Loop "Loop Collect Recurring Events" which loops collection varCollectRecurringEvents.
This goes directly (For Each) to the Inner Loop "Loop Collect Matching Events" which loops collection varCollectMatchingEvents
Then the flow goes to a Decision Element to check for Conflicting Events "Is Conflict with Recurring" with the following logic:

If it finds a conflict (outcome "Yes Recurring Conflict"), it adds the Event from the Outer Loop (from varCollectRecurringvents) to another Collection variable "varEventsToDelete".
In DEBUG Mode, this all works perfectly! It properly excludes the Master Event from the varCollectRecurringEvents. It properly extracts the 2 Conflicting Events from Event 2 and no more than those 2!
Like I said though, when Flow is ACTIVE, it deletes the whole series??
If I activate the Flow after purposely creating conflicting Events when it was DEACTIVATED, I can go to the first Event in Event 2 series and I can "update" it. When I do that, the flow acts as expected. It keeps the last instance of Event 2 and deletes the first 2 since they conflict.

Any idea why this is happening? My only assumption is that when I create Event 2, the Flow sees that the first instance of Event 2 conflicts with the first instance of Event 1. Could it be that when it deletes the first instance of Event 2 it ALSO deletes the Master even though that should be excluded from being deleted? I have the Master Activity ID in my Text Template "varActivityIds" so that Master Record is not on the chopping block directly.

If so, how can I avoid this and, furthermore, how can I actually debug for this? Could I possibly check that if the First Event of the series (not the master) is to be deleted I can save the event instances (in Event 2) in that series that DO NOT conflict and have a branch of the Flow Create those as new events and allow the Flow to delete the originals? That might be one way to accomplish this, right?

Could it be that Flow is not able to handle this and I would need to use Apex?


This is a rather intricate flow so here are screenshots of the Flow to help y'all see the Elements in all of their glory!
Screenshot 1 of the Flow

Screenshot 2 of the Flow

I'll be happy to expand on any element and provide more screenshots if necessary.
Any thoughts, help, insight, etc would be very much appreciated! I'm seriously about to throw my laptop through the window trying to figure this out...arggghhhh!!

While it's good that you have described your flow steps and troubleshooting in detail, it's hard for me to understand the actual use case that you are trying to solve.  Please [edit] your post to describe more clearly what constitutes an "overlapping" event and what specific fields are the criteria.

Thanks for the reply @DavidCheng
"Overlapping" events means Events that occur simultaneously.
If an Event has a certain Record type (Scheduling Event) and either the Subject "PTO" or the Subject "ACMO/On Call" and same Assignee (OwnerId) there cannot be any other Events that take place simultaneously with the same parameters.
So, the goal of the Flow is to look at newly Created or Updated Events and compare them to existing events with the same filtering (Record Type "Scheduling Event", "PTO" or "ACMO/ON Call" as the Subject and same Assignee (OwnerId).
Conflict=delete new Event Record

I just updated the original post to hopefully provide some clarity.

If the goal is to prevent duplicate events, it would be easier to leave the existing event and throw an error to prevent creation of the new duplicate.  As you can see, it is complicated and also inefficient to allow the new creation and then to delete the existing event.
